# How to combine tuples from two generators in python

Tags: python, generator

I want to use two generators in a single for loop. Something like:

```
for a,b,c,d,e,f in f1(arg),f2(arg):
    print a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Where a,b,c,d and e come from f1 and f comes from f2. I need to use the yield operator because of space constraints.

The above code however doesn't work. Due to some reason it keeps on taking values (for all six variables) from f1 until it is exhausted and then starts taking values from f2.

Please let me know if this is possible and if not is there any workaround. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `zip` (`itertools.izip` if you're using Python 2) and sequence unpacking:

```
def f1(arg):
    for i in range(10):
        yield 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

def f2(arg):
    for i in range(10):
        yield 6

arg = 1

for (a, b, c, d, e), f in zip(f1(arg), f2(arg)):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Comment: Nice and complete. I was providing the same answer, but this one is better.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I have a doubt though. why do we need brackets around (a,b,c,d,e)? It doesn't work without them, but what to do in case we need more than two generators?

Comment: @jackofall: Because `f1` yields a tuple. Without the parentheses you'd be trying to unpack the result of `zip()` into six variables, which won't work because `zip()` yields a 2-tuple in this case. You could have also written `for f1_item, f2_item, ... in zip(f1(arg), f2(arg), ...):` and unpacked `f1_item` and `f2_item` within the loop, but I find the shorter syntax easier to understand. Print out `f1_item` and `f2_item` within the loop body and you'll see what they contain.